# PHP MYSQLI Call to a member function bind_param()

Tags: php, mysqli

my code is

```
$query1 = "SELECT `user_id` FROM `it_user` WHERE (user_email_address = ? AND user_mobile_number_verified = NULL)";
          $stmt1 = $mysqli->prepare($query1);
          $stmt1->bind_param("s",$email);
          $stmt1->execute();
          if ($stmt1->affected_rows == 1) {
            //set registration flag to 1 stating that the users mobile number is already verified

            echo '<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; URL=\'../signin/\'"/>';
          }
          else
          {
            $registration_flag = 2;  
            //redirect user to error page
            //echo '<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; URL=\'../error/\'"/>'; 
          }
```

i am getting this error ::

Call to a member function bind_param() on a non-object in ***** on line 62

where as my email variable is working corrrect and also the query.

Comment: `user_mobile_number_verified = NULL` This is not prepared statement

Comment: Use IS NULL to check null as `user_mobile_number_verified IS NULL`

Comment: i am getting the same error even after using IS NULL

Comment: Post your full code?? include your connection ans how you get `$email`

Comment: There was an error in `prepare()`. **Output that error.** `echo $mysqli->error`.

Answer (score 0):

Use NULL safe operator and write code as below:-

```
  $mobile = NULL; // NOTE: no quotes - using php NULL
  $query1 = "SELECT `user_id` FROM `it_user` WHERE user_email_address = ? AND user_mobile_number_verified <=> ?";
  $stmt1 = $mysqli->prepare($query1);
  $stmt1->bind_param("s",$email);
  $stmt1->bind_param($mobile);
  $stmt1->execute();
```

Hope it will help you :-)

Comment: Call to a member function bind_param() on a non-object

Comment: Check updated answer.

Comment: okay, i am almost on the verge of broking now... :(

Comment: $mobile = NULL; // NOTE: no quotes - using php NULL
  $query1 = "SELECT `user_id` FROM `it_user` WHERE user_email_address = ? AND user_mobile_number_verified <=> ?)";
  $stmt1 = $mysqli->prepare($query1);
  $email = "jhaankitesh@hotmail.com";
  $stmt1->bind_param("s",$email);
  $stmt1->bind_param($mobile);
  $stmt1->execute();

this also didnt work

Comment: What error are you receiving?

Comment: Call to a member function bind_param() on a non-object